# Set default tab url in firefox 14

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, firefox-extensions, default-settings

In the latest firefox update, new tabs show -instead of the previously default blank page- a window of recently viewed pages. Before this was available, I had installed an 'addon' to allow this (called 'fvd speed dial'). It worked fine however I have since delete.d this as it is no longer needed but still loads the page where the addon was housed:'chrome://fvd.speeddial/content/fvd_about_blank.html'. I have reinstalled firefox yet the same problem still occurs. On the 'about:config' page I have found the setting 'browser.newtab.url' but do not know the default url. Is there any way to remedy this?

I will just add, I appologise if this is not the case with the new tab feature. It is all I have gathered from the firefox update page. Also, I do not want to, ideally, simply restore my settings as I have changed some of them (such as the search bar, that work fine.

I am on windows-xp, home edition. Not sure of what service pack.

Comment: You can find all the internal URLs used by Firefox at `about:about`

Answer (score 2):

The new-tab url is

```
about:newtab
```

Comment: @sebster: Accept this answer by clicking on the check below the voting controls, so that we can see that this question has been correctly answered.